# Marshmallow field of any type

Tags: python, serialization, marshmallow

I want to specify a marshmallow schema. For one of my fields, I don't want the schema to validate the type, but to simply pass it on. This is because the type could be anything, we don't know ahead of time. I don't see an option in `marshmallow.fields` for this. We want to use this as a deserializer.

For example

```
class FilterSchema(Schema):
        op = fields.Str(required=True)
        val = fields.**Any**(required=True)
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: You could try creating a custom field (https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/custom_fields.html#creating-a-field-class) but it seems like having a 'wildcard' field negates the purpose of having a schema in the first place...

Comment: I don't think it negates the purpose. You are still saying a field should be there, and even that it is required. You just aren't specifying what should be in it.

Comment: You could also try: `val = fields.Raw(required=True)` (see: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Raw)

Comment: `Raw` is the way to go. @NJM, you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`Raw()` field type](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Raw).

e.g. `val = fields.Raw(required=True)`.